# Python: How to override default logging handler?

Tags: python, logging

Suppose I have got a logger like:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Then I add a file handler to it. I want all logs go to the file and all info and above log to be printed on screen.

I know I should set the level of the file handler to logging.INFO.

However, if I use `logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)`, then the debug logs won't go to the file. If I use `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`, then all debug logs will be printed on screen.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35135401/unexpected-python-logger-output-when-using-several-handlers-with-different-log-l/35136229#35136229

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` on the logger and `handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)` on the screen handler. That way the logger gets all messages, the file handler gets all messages but the screen or stream handler gets only `INFO` or higher.

Comment: How to get the screen handler, looks like it is going to be configured through logging.basicConfig()

Comment: @dspjm Don't use `logging.basicConfig()` then and set your own `StreamHandler()` or set the level to `logging.INFO` like this: `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)`.

Comment: You can retrieve a list of handlers associated with your logger using `logger.handlers`

Comment: @Brandon bad idea mate, it's not safe. There's a reason it's not documented.

Comment: @Bharel Good to know. Thank you.

Comment: @Brandon yeah, the main concern is the fact that logging is a thread safe library and it can mess up the locks. Other problems may include stream flushing and buffering. It's better that he won't initialize a root logger at all or at least initialize it in the proper level instead of initializing and then modifying.

Comment: @Bharel looks like the best way is to setup my own StreamHandler(), however, I didn't choose this method at the beginning was because I have called the basicConifg() at the beginning of the program. So I don't know under these kind of circumstances, is there still a way to work around.

Comment: @dspjm You may create a new logger with your own `StreamHandler()` and `FileHandler()` and set [`logger.propagate = False`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate) if you can't change `basicConfig`.